# Alfresco Share:The files did not move after approve review

Tags: alfresco-share

I've created a simple workflow on folder Draft, so that if there are new documents uploaded, users will be notified about it. And if the document is approved, it will be moved to 'Pending Approval'. Since there is no due date function and task does not appear on the user's site, I tried creating an advanced workflow on the document itself and again assigned the same user to review it. However, when the user approved through the task menu, and the assignee set the task as 'Completed', the document doesn't move to the 'Pending Approval' folder.

What I wanted to do is to have the advanced workflow to trigger when new documents is added to the folder, not manually assign it to start on a specific document. An when the workflow is triggered, a task notification will be sent to the user (reviewer) with due date.

Is the only way to make this work is to build a custom workflow? If so, may I have an example, and which file should I edit? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can re-phrase your question that may make it clearer. 
What do you mean

> **if the document is approved, it will be moved to 'Pending Approval'**.

Here is one of best alfresco developer guide(in my personal view) for advance workflow. This gives step-by-step guide to create custom workflows

[Custom workflow Tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html)

You can also find code snippet to move-and-replace a file in an alfresco "Action"  [Here](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html#example-1-move-replaced)

And Complete Class code [Here](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-developer-series/blob/master/actions/actions-tutorial-repo/src/main/java/com/someco/action/executer/MoveReplacedActionExecuter.java)

Core code to "move" ONLY is :

```
public void executeImpl(Action ruleAction, NodeRef actionedUponNodeRef) {
    // get the replaces associations for this node
    List<AssociationRef> assocRefs = nodeService.getTargetAssocs(actionedUponNodeRef, ((QNamePattern) QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_1_0_URI, "replaces")) );

    // if there are none, return
    if (assocRefs.isEmpty()) {
         // no work to do, return
         return;
    } else {
        NodeRef destinationParent = (NodeRef)ruleAction.getParameterValue(PARAM_DESTINATION_FOLDER);
        for (AssociationRef assocNode : assocRefs) {
            // create a noderef for the replaces association
            NodeRef targetNodeRef = assocNode.getTargetRef();
            // if the node exists
            if (this.nodeService.exists(targetNodeRef) == true) {
                try {
                    fileFolderService.move(targetNodeRef, destinationParent, null);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
        } // next assocNode
    } // end if isEmpty
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks... But is it possible if I do the other way around, which is apply the due date and display task using execute script? Since I want the workflow to automatically run whenever a new document is inserted in the folder. From what I understand in advanced workflow, I need to specify on a document.